# Proof of vector norm formula

Tags: vector-analysis, vectors

I was trying to find something that proves the (Euclidean) vector magnitude formula for $3+$ dimensional vectors. $$\mid x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}.$$

It seems easy to prove by induction if we can show that in an $N$ dimensional space any point in $N-1$ dimension, the origin and a point in the $N$<sup>th</sup> dimension line forms a right triangle.

This is clearly true up to $3$ dimensions but I don't know how to prove this for $4$ (or higher) dimensions.

How would you prove/justify the Euclidean norm formula?

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. But why can we assume that for instance in 4 dimension, the 4th dimension is perpendicular to the 3 dimensional space?

Comment: The dimensions have to be all 'perpendicular', i.e. it is always possible to find a set of basis vectors which are mutually orthonormal *and* span the whole space.

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: Thanks. I guess my problem is that it isn't intuitive that all the dimensions are mutually orthogonal. Up to 3 it's easy to imagine/visualize it but above it just doesn't seem so obvious (to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three dimensions are easy to visualize, but after that, it gets to be rather brain-breaking to try, so I wouldn't. Adding new dimensions is somewhat like moving from real to complex numbers--we declare that there is some new structure related to the old one and satisfying certain properties (and may even go so far as to construct it set-theoretically), but we don't really worry about such a structure existing in the "real world." In this case, we simply declare that the $(n+1)$th dimension should be a dimension that is orthogonal to each of the first $n$ dimensions, and add on as many as we like in this way.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I was recapping on linear algebra (which has many real world application) and then I realized that I never questioned why is it true that higher dimensions have the same magnitude formula. When I tried to prove it I quickly realized that the dimensions need to be (mutually) orthogonal. However I couldn't see why this would be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a right triangle:
$$
\text{vertices}:\quad (\ \underbrace{0,0,0,\ldots,0}_{n\text{ components}}, 0 ),\quad (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n, 0),\quad (x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})
$$

The vector from the second point above to the third is $(0,0,\ldots,0,x_{n+1})$ and that makes a right angle with the vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0)$.

The induction hypothesis says that in $(n-1)$-dimensional space, the distance from the first point above to the second is $\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$.  The length of the vector $(0,\ldots,0,x_{n+1})$ is $|x_{n+1}|$.  So you have
$$
\sqrt{\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}^2 + |x_{n+1}|^2 } = \sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2+x_{n+1}^2}.
$$

Comment: Yes indeed, this is the inductive proof. The key thing is at the beginning that those points make a right triangle. That's only true if the axes are mutually orthogonal.