# Motivating the Definition of Magnitude of a Vector in $\mathrm{R}^n$ where $n>3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, euclidean-geometry

The definition magnitude of a vector in $\mathrm{R}^2$ can be *proved* by the Pythagorean theorem. It can also by proved for $\mathrm{R}^3$ by applying the Pythagorean theorem twice.

[image]

However, what is the motivation behind the definition of magnitude in n-dimensional euclidean space as $|\vec v| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \vec v_i^2}$?

Can this be proved to be correct for $n > 3$ the same way the definition can be proved to be correct for 2 and 3 dimensions?

Comment: One way to go is to prove it by induction.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Assume that the formula holds in $n-1$ dimensions and use that to prove that it holds in $n$ dimensions. This should require only a minor variation to the 3-D derivation.

Comment: Hm, I am failing to formulate the inductive hypothesis somehow. My idea so far was this: $|\vec v \in \mathbb{R}^n| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \vec v_i^2} = \sqrt{|\vec v_1^{n-1}|^2 + \vec v_n^2}$  where $\vec v_1^k$ denotes a vector in $k$ dimensions that shares its first $k$ entries with a vector $\vec v$ in more than $k$ dimensions. But this feels very fishy to me and not rigorous at all, truncating a vector by its components like that to bring it down to a lower dimensional space.

Comment: You’re projecting it onto a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, just as you’ve projected $\vec v$ onto the $x$-$y$ plane to get $\vec h$.

Comment: Hm that means that I then still need to define that the length of the ${n-1}$th projection of a vector is the absolute value of its first component to get a base case? $|\mathrm{prj}^{n-1}(\vec{v})| \text{ for } \vec v \in \mathbb{R}^n = |\vec v_1|$

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813969/265466) helpful.